# Retrieving Eclipse CDT Messages from Compiler

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, message, eclipse-cdt

Can we retrieve Eclipse CDT compiler problem messages (Iproblem interface) as we can do with JDT? The purpose is to access them within a standalone Java application.

```
CompilationUnit cu = …
Message[]  messages =  cu.getMessages();
IProblem[] problems = cu.getProblems();
```

It seems like there are some Java classes in the CDT API that have been removed in CDT 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in my unit test:

```
final IMarker[] markers = newProject.findMarkers(
    ICModelMarker.C_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```

Note that newProject can be any IResource - project, folder or file. You can try ITranslationUnit::getUnderlyingResource to obtain a resource from the CDT model. Note that underlying resource may be null - e.g. when the file in editor is external to the workspace.

**Update on Non-Workspace Files:**

CDT runs make externally and then parses output to extract those messages. It is unlike JDT where Java compiler living in Eclipse process is used. It looks like what you need is create a custom launcher for make, capture its output and then somehow use CDT facilities to parse the output. You will be responsible for generating error markers (or devising some other way of keeping that information). I cannot estimate how hard it would be to pass custom output through CDT error parser...

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, for your post. I will test your solution shortly. I will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Do you know if we can retrieve the markers when the file is external to the workspace?

Comment: Can you describe how you get compiler markers on external files? Mote that breakpoints (that are simply another type of marker) on external files are set as a marker on workspace root with attribute that keeps the file path.

Comment: I am still having trouble to get the markers from my parsed C source code (stored in an external file). In fact, I would like to retrieve all the error messages generated by the CDT compiler (generate and retrieve the same number of messages as it does when compiling a project in Eclipse) in a standalone Java application.

Comment: To do so, I need to bypass the Eclipse workspace and all the IResource classes (or interfaces) which would enable me to capture everything I want in a traditional Eclipse project. Moreover, I may need to set up manually within my Java application the context of my external C file in order to be able to generate the same number of notifications as in Eclipse. I am only striving to replicate what I succeeded to do with the JDT.

Comment: I added this reply to my answer - it's too long for comment.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, for your help. It gives me a pretty good idea of what is possible or not.